# Распознать текст с картинки

Tags: php

можете посоветовать готовый класс/функцию для распознавания текста с картинки?

Мне это нужно не для распознавания капчи, а именно текста. Текста определенных ошибок, которые люди не могут скопировать из окна предупреждения, поэтому нужно как-то его распознать.

присудствующие языки - английский, и желательно русский
спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Вот Вам пример:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';
    use bpteam\phpOCR\Recognizer;
    use bpteam\phpOCR\Img;
    $file_name = __DIR__ . '/template/test_img/olx1.png';
    $ex = 'png';
    Recognizer::setInfelicity(10);
    $img = Recognizer::openImg($file_name);
    //Source image
    echo "<br>Step 0 src img<br>";
    Img::show($img,$ex,100);
    //load template
    $name = 'olx';
    Recognizer::setTemplateDir(__DIR__ . '/template/');
    $template = Recognizer::loadTemplate($name);
    // OCR
    echo "<br>defineImg<br>";
    $text = Recognizer::read($file_name, $template);
    echo $text."<br>";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно ссылку на сам класс

Comment: @turik97 https://github.com/bpteam/php-ocr

Comment: В предыдущем ответе от автора **@Unfex**, где указывается архив github.com/bpteam/php-ocr в качестве исходного класса, отсутствует необходимый файл `bootstrap.php`, пожалуйста укажите ссылку на корректный класс, так как данный скрипт без полного класса не работает...